# Plotting Percentages of each Group in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

Well, I have a dataframe that like this one:

[image]

'ca' is a categorical variable ranging from 0 to 4. I want to plot the density (percentage) of the patients corresponding to each 'ca' value and grouping them with the target value.

I have a round about way which works but I am thinking there has to be more elegant solution. First, I am grouping all the data by 'ca' and 'target':

```
df_ca = df_cat.groupby(['ca','target']).count()

df_ca
```

[image]

Then I am summing up the all values in 'age' column for each 'ca' value and dividing the current counts by it to get percentage values and dropping all the other columns:

```
df_ca.iloc[0:2] /= df_ca.iloc[0:2].age.sum()
df_ca.iloc[2:4] /= df_ca.iloc[2:4].age.sum()
df_ca.iloc[4:6] /= df_ca.iloc[4:6].age.sum()
df_ca.iloc[6:8] /= df_ca.iloc[6:8].age.sum()
df_ca.iloc[8:10] /= df_ca.iloc[8:10].age.sum()
df_ca = df_ca.reset_index(level='target')
df_ca = df_ca[['age','target']]
df_ca.rename(columns={'age':'Ca_density'},inplace=True)
df_ca
```

[image]

After that all I have to do is plotting to final dataframe:

[image]

I think this is kind of a mess and I am not sure how can I do this easier.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please have a look at [mcve] and provide copy pastable code instead of screenshots, especially your starting dataframe.

Comment: Looks like you can do `df.groupby('ca')['target'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack('target')`.